# Find the limit point of set A in topology

Tags: general-topology

Find limit points of set A

A = {$n\sin\frac{1}{n}+(-1)^n\frac{1}{m}$ where $n,m\in N$}

i think

A' = {1, 0}

but i can't prove this problem.

Help

Comment: A'={n*sin(1/n) where n in N}

Comment: In addition to the points mentioned in the comment, we have $1$ and all points $1\pm \frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: could you prove this problem? please help me

Comment: Not today, it is getting very late here. But as a hint, let $a$ be a limit point, and let $(a_i)$ be a sequence with limit $a$. There are three possibilities: (i) there are infinitely many $n$ but finitely many $m$; (ii) the other way around; (iii) infinitely many of both.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll try again

Comment: In particular, you can fix any $n$ and let $m$ go to infinity, and that yields lots of limit points that nobody has mentioned yet.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_{n,m}=n\sin(1/n)+(-1)^n/m$. Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ be a **convergent** sequence of distinct elements of $A$.

We first look at the case where the sequence contains points $p_{n,m}$  of $A$ with arbitrarily large values of $n$ and $m$. Since $n\sin(1/n)$ has limit $1$, and the $1/m$ have limit $0$, our sequence converges to $1$.

Now suppose that the sequence only contains the points $p_{n,m}$ of $A$ in the sequence have bounded $n$ and unbounded $m$. Then since $1/m$ has limit $0$, our sequence must have limit $q\sin(1/q)$ for some $q$.

Finally, suppose that in the $p_{n,m}$ in the sequence, $n$ are unbounded and the $m$ are bounded. Then the $n\sin(1/n)$ part has limit $1$, while the $(-1)^n/m$ part, if it converges, must converge to $1/k$ or $-1/k$ for some fixed $k$. That gives limit points $1\pm 1/k$.

In particular, for $k=1$, we get your $0$ from $1-1/1$.

So your points are indeed limit points, but there are two families of others.